# Rejecting Email with Postfix smtpd_sender_restrictions

Tags: postfix

I'm having some trouble blocking email sent with a particular "From" address. The email header looks like this:

```
From: "Levi Spammer" <lspammer@iamspammer.com>
```

My postfix config looks like this:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access_hash,
        check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/access.pcre,
        permit
```

I have this entry in the access_hash file:

```
iamspammer.com     REJECT
```

and this in access.pcre:

```
/iamspammer.com/   REJECT
```

and yet email sent from this address isn't being rejected. It's being delivered. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_sender_access` rules are applied to the **[SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) Envelope `FROM` address** (i.e. from the `MAIL FROM:` stage of the SMTP protocol negotiation), not to the **`From:` header** in the message itself.

This confuses a lot of people new to how email and SMTP works, but it's important to realise that the envelope `FROM` address is completely different from and unrelated to the message header `From:` (for pretty much the same reason that the address written on a real-world posted letter's envelope is/can be entirely unrelated to any salutations or greetings in the actual letter inside the envelope).  They are two entirely separate and unrelated things.  BTW, the envelope FROM address is usually referred to as all-capitals FROM or FROM_ (FROM followed by underscore), while the header From: address is usually referred to as mixed-case "From:" (including the `:`) - this helps to distinguish between them.

A very simplified summary of an [STMP session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example) starts with the sender machine connecting to the recipient machine (usually on port 25 or 465 or 587) and opening negotiation with an `EHLO` or `HELO` command (to identify itself).  If that is accepted, then it sends a `MAIL FROM:` command.  This is the **envelope sender (or `FROM`) address**.  If that is accepted it sends one or more `RCPT TO:` statements listing the recipients of the message.  If the recipient machine accepts one or more of the recipients as valid destination addresses, the sender then sends a `DATA` command followed by the message itself (which is generally a block of message headers like From:, Date:, Subject:, etc followed by an empty line and then the actual body of the message.  The `DATA` block is terminated by a `.` on a line by itself), and the SMTP session is terminated with the `QUIT` command.

Note that the header From: address may be the same as the envelope FROM address, or it may be very similar (e.g. the envelope address with additional info like the person's actual name), or it may be completely different (e.g. the envelope FROM address may be a mailing list's address, while the header From: contains the original sender's address).

For more info about difference between these two things, there are reasonable explanations of the difference between envelope FROM and header From: at [Legitimate reasons SMTP “MAIL FROM:” will not match “From:” Header in DATA](https://serverfault.com/questions/518119/legitimate-reasons-smtp-mail-from-will-not-match-from-header-in-data)

---

Anyway, after all that background info, if you want to apply anti-spam rules to message headers like `From:` or `Subject:` in Postfix, you need to use [header_checks](https://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) rules and/or configure Postfix to use an external [Milter](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html) ("mail filter") program.

Answer (score 1):

I have

```
check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender,
```

as part of my restrictions.

In my `sender` file I have entries such as

```
iamspammer.com  554 Spam not welcome here
idiot@anotherspammer.com 554 Spam not welcome here
```

This will cause that 554 error (including message) to appear at the SMTP layer.

After this file has been built you then need to build the hash file:

```
postmap sender
```

You should end up with `sender.db` and that's the file that's used.

Comment: Right, I should have mentioned that I'm also using postmap to build the hash map.

We're basically doing the same thing, except that you're being specific about the SMTP return code. According to the postfix ACCESS man page (http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html), REJECT should work:

REJECT optional text...
              Reject the address etc. that matches the  pattern.  Reply  with
              "$access_map_reject_code  optional  text..."  when  the optional
              text is specified, otherwise reply with a generic error response
              message.